# limitation on "add more" button: Drupal 7

Tags: forms

I am using add more for a field which provide only maximum limit But I want to add by default two fields with "add more" button up to a maximum number of 10 fields.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Are you looking for the  http://drupal.org/project/field_collection module? pls clarify your requirement

Comment: Thanks!! I have a form with some fields (say name, url, token). I want to provide "add more" button for token field with two token fields by default (drupal gives one by default) and maximum 10 token fields (drupal gives it) when user is filling form. I think now you have idea what i want.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're after the [Multivalue Settings](http://drupal.org/project/multivalue_settings) module.

> So you can create fields where, for instance, users have to input at
>   least 5 values but can input up to 10 values. Or you can create fields
>   that allow 100 values, but only display 20 fields to start with.

**HOWEVER** (and this is a big however - if I could change the font size I would)

This module should probably only be used as a starting point, and should not be used in production. I'm sure you can get the code you need from it.

> Warning: this module is still very buggy. Actually, it only works in 
>   very few use cases. I suggest to only attempt using it with core
>   fields (not fields from contrib modules). Even this may not work. I'm
>   working on fixing things, but don't have much time. Help is welcome.

Comment: This module is still buggy as written on the description page. Could you advice another solution?

Comment: I tried the module. It's really buggy and should not be used on production. Looking forward for other solitions